# Create new user, mailbox, and other stuf

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, exchange-2010, lync

I have a small active directory but want to be able to create and delete users from 1 point. I think powershell is a good way to do this.

But is it possible to create a user, homedir, profile, mailbox and lync user from one powershell window?

And if this is possible can someone please send me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Check out ADSI (Active Directory Services Interface):  http://psobject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ADSI%20and%20AD

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Use PowerShell IDE to create the script and test each command based on variables you ask the admin for.

The script will have to load the cmdlets for each tool.  One for AD, one for Lync, one for Exchange.  First the tools will need to be installed on the computer where you run the PowerShell script from.

ADSI can do the AD stuff but is only part of the problem so I would stick with pure PowerShell cmdlets.

I recommend doing this on Windows Server 2008 R2 which has the AD Module for PowerShell feature.